# raspberry pi 4 onboard virtual keyboard AT-SPI: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus. Is at-spi-bus-launcher running?

Tags: raspberry-pi, virtual-keyboard

I installed "onboard" as a virtual keyboard on the system. It looked much nicer and more useful than matchbox. I went into the settings and chose the auto open option when I edit the post. after that i restarted my raspberry pi. As it didn't come on automatically, I couldn't run it from the terminal or the menu normally. The error I get when I try to run it from terminal[image]

Comment: at least i got the keyboard working again for now. For this, I turned off the "auto-on" feature "on my raspi>preferences">"on-screen keyboard settings", and . keyboard still works. But I have no idea how to activate the auto-open feature.

Comment: did you ever get auto-show working?

Answer (score 2):

Hej blackmamba,

I had the same issue with the on screen keyboard [florence](http://florence.sourceforge.net/english.html). After I installed `at-spi2-core`, it didn't crash anymore, though i could not get it to open automatically.

So I tried installing [onboard](https://launchpad.net/onboard) and everything worked quiet well. Might be a hint..

regards, jarvis

- Raspberry Pi B+
- 5.10.63 Kernel
- Debian Buster 10
- Waveshare 10.1" HDMI LCD Touch Display